# Actions not being dispatched to reducers after being called by the props

Tags: react-native, redux, react-redux

I'm new to redux and trying to make a simple react-native app.

Actions are being mapped to props (mapDispatchToProps) but they are not being dispatched to reducers. When I do console.log() in the Action Creators, they are being called but when I do console.log() in the CounterReducer, they are not called.

App.js

```
class App extends React.Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <Provider store={store}>
        <HomeScreen />
      </Provider>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

HomeScreen.js

```
class HomeScreen extends React.Component {
  incrementCounter = () => {
    this.props.incrementCounter();
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.mainContainer}>
        <Text>Open up App.js to start working on your app!</Text>
        <Text>{this.props.counter}</Text>
        <Button title="Click me " onPress={this.incrementCounter} />
        <Button
          title="Create Counter"
          onPress={() => {
            this.props.createCounter(5);
          }}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  counter: state.counter
});

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
  incrementCounter: incrementCounter,
  createCounter: createCounter
});

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(HomeScreen);
```

store.js

```
const reducers = combineReducers({
    counterReducer
})

const store = createStore(reducers)

export default store;
```

counterReducer.js

```
const counterReducer = (state = {}, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case actionTypes.CREATE_COUNTER:
      state.counter = action.payload;
      return { ...state };
    case actionTypes.INCREMENT_COUNTER:
      state.counter++;
      return { ...state };
    default:
      return { ...state };
  }
};

export default counterReducer;
```

actions.js

```
export const actionTypes = {
    INCREMENT_COUNTER: "INCREMENT_COUNTER",
    CREATE_COUNTER: "CREATE_COUNTER",
}

export const incrementCounter = () => {
  return {
    type: actionTypes.INCREMENT_COUNTER
  };
};

export const createCounter = value => ({
  type: actionTypes.CREATE_COUNTER,
  payload: value
});
```

I have tried doing this in the HomeScreen but it gives me the error that actions must be plain objects and to use Middleware for async actions, even when I don't have any async actions.

```
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
  incrementCounter: () => dispatch(incrementCounter),
  createCounter: () => dispatch(createCounter)
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can modify your `mapDispatchToProps` in a couple of ways to fix this. The simplest is just to pass a plain object:

```
const mapDispatchToProps = {
  incrementCounter: incrementCounter,
  createCounter: createCounter
};
```

React-redux will automatically bind the action creators to `dispatch`.

To use the other approach you would have to call the action creators inside of dispatch like so:

```
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
  incrementCounter: () => dispatch(incrementCounter()),
  createCounter: () => dispatch(createCounter())
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you forgot to add paranthesis at the end of function call

DO IT LIKE THIS

```
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
  incrementCounter: () => dispatch(incrementCounter()),
  createCounter: () => dispatch(createCounter())
});
```